# Enabling constrained delegation on DC computer account

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, delegation

Is it necessary to have constrained delegation enabled on Microsoft AD domain controller computer account? If yes then why and what are consequences of disabling it?
I'm mainly interested in current versions of Windows Server 2008/2012, though don't mind to know about history - i.e. how it was in previous versions :)

Comment: You may want to explain that a little further. Are you seeing any issues? Are you having security concerns?

Comment: Rather want to know how it's configured by default (enabled or disabled). And IF enabled by default what for?